# How to retieve values from Flow<List<Obj>> and add all of them to <List<Int>>?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

In ViewModel:

```
val drillerCatList: List<Int> = emptyList()

val shownCategoriesFlow = wordDao.getShownCategories() // which returns type Flow<List<CategoryItem>>
```

Catigory object:

```
data class CategoryItem(
    val categoryName: String,
    val categoryNumber: Int,
    val categoryShown: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {
}
```

How can I retrieve all categoryNumber values from shownCategoriesFlow: FLow<List> and fill drillerCatList: List with these values in ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make drillerCatList mutable as shown below:

```
val drillerCatList: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

Now collect the list from the `shownCategoriesFlow`:

```
shownCategoriesFlow.collect {
   it.forEach{ categoryItem ->
        drillerCatList.add(categoryItem.categoryNumber)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your property either needs to be a `MutableList` or a `var`. Usually, `var` with a read-only `List` is preferable since it is less error-prone. Then you call `collect` on your Flow in a coroutine. `collect` behaves sort of like `forEach` does on an Iterable, except that it doesn't block the thread in between when elements are ready.

```
val drillerCatList: List<Int> = emptyList()

val shownCategoriesFlow = wordDao.getShownCategories()

init { // or you could put this in a function do do it passively instead of eagerly
    viewModelScope.launch {
        shownCategoriesFlow.collect { drillerCatList = it.map(CategoryItem::categoryNumber) }
    }
}
```

Alternate syntax:

```
init {
    shownCategoriesFlow
        .onEach { drillerCatList = it.map(CategoryItem::categoryNumber) }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```